# Angular Multi-item carousel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Ive been trying to make the angular carousel work, but iam currently stuck. 
I am a newbie in angular, thus can i not get the ng-repeat too work correct.

what ive done:

```
 <div id="slides_control">
<div>
  <carousel interval="3000">
    <slide ng-repeat="book in bookslider" active="book.active">
      <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{book.img}}"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{book[$index +1].img}}"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{book[$index +2].img}}"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{book[$index +3].img}}"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

```
 $scope.bookslider = [

    {

        img: "images/headerslider/5.jpg"
    },
    {

        img: "images/headerslider/4.jpg"
    },
    {

        img: "images/headerslider/2.jpg"
    },
    {
        img: "images/headerslider/3.jpg"
    }
];
```

This display only the first image because it cannot "render" -  book[$index +1].img 
how would one go about getting the next index item for this situation?

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/VcD8tKOtfQGuOgt4tO08

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle?

Comment: @Nitheesh  Ive added a working plunk to the question :-)

Comment: The plunker seems to work fine. Whats the issue?

Comment: @Nitheesh i want to display 4 images in the same carousel, currently it is only displaying the one image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gone through the plunker you provided and I under stand your requirement. I think the mistake that you made is where you loop the `bookslider` object. You need to loop through `bookslider` object instead of that you looped through the `book` object which is actually an individual object of the `bookslider` array.

You just change the carousel object like this to fix the issue.

```
<carousel interval="3000">
    <slide ng-repeat="book in bookslider track by $index" active="book.active">
        <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{bookslider[($index) %4 ].img}}" style="width=100px"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{bookslider[($index+1) % 4].img}}"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{bookslider[($index+2) % 4].img}}"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><img ng-src="{{bookslider[($index+3) % 4].img}}"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
        </div>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

I have attached the working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RydNRq8WYUYjjDVL5x0m?p=preview).